# Drools rules execution hangs

Tags: drools

The following rule hangs drools:

```
rule "Sound the alarm in case temperature rises above threshold"
when
    $m1 : TempReading( temp >= 35 )
    Number( doubleValue >= 2 ) from accumulate(
        TempReading( temp >= 35, this after[0s, 1m] $m1 ),
            init( double total = 0; ),
            action( total += 1; ),
            reverse( total -= 1; ),
            result( total ) ) 
then
    System.out.println("Temp over max")
end
```

I have log statements in ObjectXXXEvents which are all logged tight away.
It looks like this:

```
Object inserted 
com.sample.DroolsTest$TempReading@6bab2585
Object inserted 
com.sample.DroolsTest$TempReading@a486d78
Object inserted 
com.sample.DroolsTest$TempReading@cdc3aae
Object inserted 
com.sample.DroolsTest$TempReading@7ef2d7a6
Object inserted 
com.sample.DroolsTest$TempReading@5dcbb60
```

I have log statements for matchCreated, matchCancelled, beforeMatchFired and afterMatchFired and NONE of them are logged.

If I change the clockType to `psuedo` it exits but the rule does not fire.

What gives?

Comment: Is this the only rule you have? Could you share some of the `ObjectXXXEvent` logs that you mentioned?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti upated with log ouput. Only rule.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti If I change the clockType to psuedo it exits but the rule does not fire.

Comment: How are you feeding these facts to your session and how are you firing your rules?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by not using STREAM mode.  I thought timestamps required STREAM mode but that is not necessary.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Can you help with with another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195212/how-to-parameterize-the-after-temporal-constraint-in-drools ?