# How to parameterize the after temporal constraint in Drools?

Tags: drools

I have a rule very similar to the following example:

```
rule "correlate orders"
when
    $bo : BuyOrderEvent( $id : id ) 
    $ae : AckEvent( id == $id, this after[0,10s] $bo )
then
    // do something
end
```

But I would like to parameterize the time (10 seconds in this example).

I tried using a String variable but I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing time string: [ $t1.max ]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you manage to do that?

Comment: Yes. I generated the required script at run time. See https://github.com/sureshvv/drools-poc